# Rails: NameError: uninitialized constant on join table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I can't seem to work around the name convention or if I'm joining them incorrectly.

This is the error I'm getting from the user model:

```
> user.companies
NameError: uninitialized constant User::CompaniesUser
```

And from the company model:

```
> company.users
NameError: uninitialized constant Company::CompaniesUser
```

user.rb

```
has_many :companies_users
has_many :companies, :through => :companies_users
```

company.rb

```
has_many :companies_users
has_many :users, :through => :companies_users
```

company_user.rb

```
class CompanyUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I've been looking up through examples but I honestly don't understand why it keeps exploding. If there's any additional information needed, I'll provide it, I appreciate any help given.

Answer (score 6):

Your association `companies_users` will be mapped to class named `CompaniesUser` by Rails because `"companies_users".classify` will give you `CompaniesUser`.  But the class you want to associate is `CompanyUser`, so the solution in this case would be to modify your associations to include `class_name` option as follows:

```
# user.rb

has_many :companies_users, class_name: CompanyUser
has_many :companies, :through => :companies_users

# company.rb

has_many :companies_users, class_name: CompanyUser
has_many :users, :through => :companies_users
```

Update: This is of course if you want to stick with the association name `companies_users`, otherwise @Babur has a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
has_many :company_users
has_many :companies, :through => :company_users
```

Only last word should be pluralized

Answer (score 0):

Because of your `has_many :companies_users` in your `Company` model, Rails tried to load a model class for that table, that be convention would be called `CompaniesUser`. To make your code work, you could either change your `has_many` declaration to

```
has_many :company_users
```

or even get rid of the `CompanyUser` model completely and use `has_and_belongs_to_many` instead.

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end

class Company
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```